# curl not working when pasting the same url which works in browser address bar

Tags: c, libcurl

I am trying to use libcurl c api to post some thing on to a site. The url works when i access it from the browser. I copied the same from the browser bar and accessing it in the program. The program hangs in the curl_easy_perform call and never returns. I also provide a write_callback but it never gets invoked. 
whats wrong with this piece of code below

for privacy reasons i removed the url from the piece of code below .

```
int main(void)
{
    CURLcode res;

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, ""); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1L );
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1L );
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK) fprintf(stderr,"failed: %s", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the site you are trying to fetch makes some restrictions(For example: UA, Referrer)

Comment: Have you tried running this with a more generally available website?  I ran your example with http://google.com, and it worked just fine.  Of course, I just printed out the size/nmemb values passed to the write_callback, so it's impossible to tell if there's something wrong with your callback func.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` as well.

So if your post looks like http://awesome.com/superpost.html?blah=hi

- URL should be: http://awesome.com/superpost.html
- POSTFIELDS should be: blah=hi
- CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE should be: strlen("blah=hi")

There are some decent examples on the curl site:

- basic post: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplepost.html
- more elaborate: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html

Note: You'll also want to escape your post field key/values with `curl_escape`

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be withe type of url encoding. So try to see how to encode the data sent to that url proper. according to the server. in php you can use `rawurlencode` with is different from `url-encode` and may affet the server reply.